# Link spacing in JSX in accordance with Airbnb style guide

Tags: reactjs, eslint-config-airbnb

Say that I want to satisfy Airbnb style guide's rules in linting. How should I go about embedding a link in line with other text in JSX (using React)?

For me, the natural way to do this would be:

```
<footer>
  Source available <a href="#">here</a>.
</footer>
```

However, this throws `react/jsx-one-expression-per-line`.

The simplest way to pass the linter leaves no space between the previous word and the link (it also looks horrific):

```
<footer>
  Source available
  <a href="#">here</a>
  .
</footer>
```

The following two solutions give correct spacing but are pretty verbose compared to the first one using just three lines and being extremely legible:

```
<footer>
  Source available
  {' '}
  <a href="#">here</a>
  .
</footer>

// Same result:

<footer>
  {'Source available '}
  <a href="#">here</a>
  .
</footer>
```

Is there a way to satisfy this ruleset with clear and concise code, such as the three-line example in the beginning of this post?

Comment: Why not change the rule set to suit your style?

Comment: @FortyTwo you are correct in that modifying the ruleset would allow me to use my style without linting errors. However, I was more interested in how this should be done if one was required to strictly adhere to this ruleset.